# Scratching noise from microphone

Tags: sound, microphone, mumble

Good evening,
when i use mumble or teamspeak, people are complaining that with my voice they also hear some scratching noises. Do i need any driver to have the sound clean? I do not have this problem in Win7, the sound there is clean. Any ideas?